# apply bottom border to active tab in Atom

Tags: styles, atom-editor

I have been looking around for a while on how to apply a bottom border to the actively selected tab in Atom.  I have tried adding different code I found to the styles.less file but it doesn't seem to be applying. What is the proper code to highlight the bottom border of the active tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct code. Just add it to your styles.less file.

```
tabs-tab, .tab {
    &.active {
        &:before{
            border-bottom: solid 4px blue;
        } &:after{
            border-bottom: solid 4px blue;
        }
        border-bottom: solid 4px blue;
    }
}
```

Obviously you could change the height and color, but this will show the border.